# How to make keyCode == ENTER update a string?

Tags: variables, processing, enter, weather

I have my programme here, where you can see I have a string called "S", and a void Get Temperature. At the bottom where keypresses are processed, it has an else If statement with ENTER. I want it so that when you press enter, it updates the string (s) to whatever you have typed, and then load it into the "SetAddress" field. How would I go about this?

```java
import com.temboo.core.*;
import com.temboo.Library.Yahoo.Weather.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
AudioPlayer player;
Minim minim;
PImage bg;
String myText;
PFont Bold;
PFont Thin;
TembooSession session = new TembooSession("goldsmiths-c", "myFirstApp", "CNgLbwqnqzGdsnk6wHXPfAnQNSmV0Fmr");
String s = "Enter Location";
int prev = frameCount;
//KeyPressed KeyPressed = new KeyPressed();

void setup() {
  size(960, 540);
  bg = loadImage("mountains.jpg");
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("song.mp3");
  player.play();
  player.loop();
  runGetTemperatureChoreo(); 
  Bold = createFont ("TTFirsBlackItalic.otf", height);
  Thin = createFont ("TTFirsThin.otf", height);
  frameRate (30);
}

void draw() {
  background(bg);
  fill (0);
  textFont (Bold);
  textSize (48);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  text(myText, 10, 390);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  textFont (Thin);
  textSize (48);
  text(s, 10, 500);
  print(mouseY);
}

void runGetTemperatureChoreo() {

  GetTemperature getTemperatureChoreo = new GetTemperature(session);

  getTemperatureChoreo.setAddress(s);
  getTemperatureChoreo.setUnits("c");

  GetTemperatureResultSet getTemperatureResults = getTemperatureChoreo.run();
  myText = (s) + (getTemperatureResults.getTemperature() + ("°c"));
  print(getTemperatureResults.getTemperature());
}
void keyPressed()
{
  if (keyPressed && prev <= frameCount-10) { //If a key is being pressed, and the security/delay is fine with it
    prev = frameCount; //re-Init the clock
    if (keyCode == BACKSPACE) { //Delete a char!
      if (s.length() > 0) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
      }
    } else if (keyCode == DELETE) {
      s = "";
    } else if (keyCode == ENTER && s.length() != 0) {
    } else if (keyCode != SHIFT && keyCode != CONTROL && keyCode != ALT && s.length() < 20) { //It's an ok char, add it to the String
      s += key;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you're storing what the user types in the `s` variable. You then have this part of your if statement:

```java
else if (keyCode == ENTER && s.length() != 0) {
}
```

That `else if` will be entered whenever the user presses enter after typing something. So you just have to put whatever code you want inside the body of that statement:

```java
else if (keyCode == ENTER && s.length() != 0) {
   getTemperatureChoreo.setAddress(s);
}
```

I might not be fully understanding your code, so this is just an example. But the basic idea is the same: to do something when the user presses enter, just put the code you want to happen inside this `else if` block.

In the future, please try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire sketch. For example, your question has nothing to do with minim, so you can get rid of all of that code. Start over with a blank sketch and only add enough code so we can copy and paste it to run it ourselves to see where you're stuck. Good luck.